# how refresh image name automatically using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Hello I use this script [SimpleImage](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage)

```html
  // making SimpleImage instances of selected friends including main image
  $img = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage('main.jpg');
  //$img1 = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage($friend1);
  //$img2 = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage($friend2);
  //$img3 = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage($friend3);
```

how refresh image name `main.jpg` automatically after refresh the page using javascript or jQuery ?

I tried this tutorial [jQuery DIV Auto Load and Refresh](http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-div-auto-load-and-refresh/)

This variable is placed somewhere image `<?php echo $bg_array[$bg];?>` But it did not work

All I want is to update `main.jpg` every time the page is loaded

Comment: You cannot change an image name in a PHP code with Javascript. PHP is run on the server while the javascript is run on the client **after** the server processed the request.

Comment: OK 
Is it possible to change the image name using the php?
How so?

Comment: You can pass any filename you want to SimpleImage. You just need to make that dynamic and not pass a static string to it. If `$bg_array[$bg]` contains a randomly selected filename, you can pass that variable to SimpleImage.

Comment: I tried this it did not succeed `$img = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage($bg_array[$bg]);`

Comment: `It did not succeed` doesn't describe what doesn't work. It just tells me something doesn't work. I still don't know what doesn't work.

Comment: You must change the name to the image main.jpg or main2.jpg
Nothing happens and is not generating a new image
`$bg_array = array("main2.jpg","'main.jpg");
$bg = array_rand($bg_array,1);`

Comment: Sorry
I use Google translate

Comment: You have a single quote mixed into your filename `"'main.jpg"` <-- directly after the double quote is a single quote, remove that one.

Comment: You correct the error
It did not work

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101525/discussion-between-mouhssin-duoi-and-charlotte-dunois).

Comment: if you change directly ($img = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage('main2.jpg');), does it work?

Comment: Test :

$img_array= array("main2.jpg","main.jpg");

$img = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage($img_array[0].".jpg");

Comment: I tried did not work